# Position div at position of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to position an `div` exactly on top of another. I'm doing it through JQuery (and not css), because I have 3 elements. When the mouse goes over one of the elements, I want the `div` to position itself to that element.

I finally got it to work, but when the `div` goes over to the element, the `div` goes there, and adds 8px to the left.

How can I position a `div` at the exact position of another element?

#### JSFiddle

```js
$('.inner').mouseover(function() {
  var pos = $(this).position();
  $("#back").css('left', pos.left + "px");
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 30px;
}
.inner {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
}
#back {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">First Option</div>
  <div class="inner">Second Option</div>
  <div class="inner">Third Option</div>
  <div id="back"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: any reason you're not doing this in pure css?

Comment: Because in my actual project, It's going to be click.().

Comment: After resetting the default `margin` and `padding` of `body` [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6gvrt7nq/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the extra space by setting `position: absolute` to the `#back` element. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6gvrt7nq/19/)**

Easy, right? **But why?**

When using `position: relative`, as stated in the [W3schools property page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp):

> An element with position: relative; is positioned **relative to its normal position**.

By default all elements have `position: static`, which basically means that where and how you construct your elements in your document, that's where they will be and it's really referred to as [*not* being *positioned*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

When you add `position: relative` to an element, it takes it's current position and then *adds* or *subtracts* it's position further depending on what values you gave to the properties `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` (also note, the major difference between `static` and `relative` is that `relative` can accept these properties, they won't affect a `static` element).

In your case you were adding the property `left` with a value you were getting from the `position()` method (let's say `8px` like your first example`). That means that`#back`was being a positioned`8px`*from* the it's original position, which was already positioned`8px`from the left (due to the document's`padding`/`margin`).

In order to make the element not be affected by `margin` or `padding` you have to take it out of the document flow with `position: absolute`. With absolute positioning the element won't "take up space" in the document like a `static` or `relative` element will, so it won't then be affected by parent elements' `padding` or `margin` properties.

Unless you are 100% positive no parent elements will have `margin` or `padding` value that will affect the element that is positioned `relative` then sometimes you can get away with not changing the element to `absolute`.

**[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gvrt7nq/16/)** shows the `#back` element with `position: relative`.

**[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gvrt7nq/17/)** shows why you should give it `position: absolute` (once padding is introduced, everything gets messy.

With that same `padding` and `position: absolute` everything is working as intended again- **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6gvrt7nq/18/)** (*pretty much*).

Comment: Thanks! Very well stated!! The problem with the demos is that `#back's` width is ignored. The only demo that the width works is the 3rd to last one. (This demo shows the #back element with position: relative.)

Comment: But I'll give +1 for the well stated answer! :)

Comment: @Jessica the `width` isn't ignore - it's using `calc(100%/3)` (your original value); you will have to adjust when using `position: absolute`--- `absolute` is relative to the nearest positioned element, which in your case in the document (no parent positioned) - so you have to be explicit with your widths - **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gvrt7nq/20/)** - `calc()` the padding  and `position` the parent will yield the same `width` for `#back` and `.inner` when `#back` is `absolute` but I'm sure other adjustments will be needed to bring in the solution:)

Answer (score 2):

.wrapper should be relative position and .back should be absolute position

```js
$('.inner').mouseover(function() {
  var pos = $(this).position();
  $("#back").css('left', pos.left + "px");
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  
  
}
#back {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 125;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">First Option</div>
  <div class="inner">Second Option</div>
  <div class="inner">Third Option</div>
  <div id="back"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I add animation to `#back`?

Comment: Also, is it necessary to have a position of absolute for `#back`? `relative` works just as well in your example.

Comment: When working with position: relative; the way the object in question is positioned is indeed relative to page margins of your document or relevant divs.

Comment: Absolute positioning can result in overlapping elements because objects are being placed in specific locations of the relative document.

Comment: So you're suggesting I give `#back` relative positioning?

Comment: Yes give relative to #back and animation is here

 $("#back").animate({left: pos.left}, "slow");

Comment: Oh. Got it! Thanks! When I do `transition: left linear 1s;`, the animation doesn't happen on the first time the mouse enters.

Answer (score 0):

```
back div should have position absolute to get on other div's.
```

Please find updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surajAhirrao/6gvrt7nq/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that before, and as you can see, `#back` looses it's width of `calc(100%/3)`

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to `#wrapper`.

So `#wrapper` should look like:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    height:30px;
    position: relative;
}
```